# Difference between Tarjan's algorithm and Kahn's algorithm for topological sort

Tags: algorithm, topological-sort

What is the difference between Tarjan's algorithm and Kahn's algorithm for Topological Sort? Which one is more efficient?

Answer (score -1):

[Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) is not, as its name indicates, an algorithm for topological sorting. It only produces a reverse topological sort of the strongly connected components.

[Usual algorithms for topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Algorithms), including Kahn's algorithm, have a complexity in `O(|V|+|E|)`.

Comment: The DFS-based topological sort algorithm in the second link you give is attributed to Tarjan; this is the algorithm the OP is asking about, not the SCC one.

Comment: @adl And yet searching for "Tarjan's algorithm" will only show you his SCC algorithm. And since it does sort the SCCs, I'd wager the OP was confused about it. If not, he probably should have specified exactly which was the algorithm in question, and provided links. There is a reason why the DFS topological sorting algorithm isn't called "Tarjan's topological sorting algorithm".